# Python pandas dataframe multiple date time conversions

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm reading values into excel datasheet using python.
I have a column with date values and some of the date values have multiple values:

```
1441152000000.0
1441756800000
1476316800000,1482192000000,1440547200000,1453248000000,1460505600000
1465430400000
1476921600000 
1450224000000.0
1449014400000
```

I'm using panda's to_datetime:

```
df.iloc["colname"] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc["colname"], unit='ms', utc=True)
```

And it crashes at this line. I think it is expected as it is a list in a list and to_datetime does not know how to deal with it. 
I tried to modify to convert cell by cell, but this gives me some errors as well:

```
for ii in range(0, len(df.axes[0])):
     jj=df.columns.get_loc(col)
     df.iloc[ii,jj] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[ii,jj], unit='ms', utc=True)
```

This gives: "raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"

I'm not sure what else I can try at this point...

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with those extra values? Get rid of it?

Comment: That's what I'm getting from a client, and he insists he wants to keep it this way in excel - i.e. combination of single and multiple dates.

Comment: I'd ask the client "why", and then when he/she answers, "why" again :). Basically, it's good to understand the end goal / big picture.

Comment: Use `df["colname"] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc["colname"], unit='ms', utc=True, errors='coerce')` and don't tell your client what it does ;)

Comment: Could you just split that entry with 5 dates into 5 separate rows?

Comment: You could use a multiIndex, with the record and date

Answer (score 1):

Process in two steps: first, convert column to a column of lists (using ast for packed cells), then recreate the dataframe.

Then you can call your function :

```
import ast

#convert packed cells to list
indexes = df[df['colname'].apply(lambda x: not (isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float)) and "," in x)].index
df.loc[indexes, 'colname'] = df.loc[indexes, 'colname'].apply(lambda x:ast.literal_eval( "[" + x +"]"))

#convert unpacked cells to list
indexes = df[df['colname'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float))].index
df.loc[indexes, "colname"] = df.loc[indexes, "colname"].apply(lambda x: [x,])

#Recreate dataframe
vals = [[unique, *vals] for colname, *vals in df.values.tolist() for unique in colname]
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns = df.columns.tolist())

#Secure data type
df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype(float)

#Apply your function
df["colname"] = pd.to_datetime(df["colname"], unit='ms', utc=True)
```

---

**Edit to match your real columns:**

```
import ast
for colname in ['Date', 'Created']:
    #convert packed cells to list
    indexes = df[df[colname].apply(lambda x: not (isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float)) and "," in x)].index
    df.loc[indexes, colname] = df.loc[indexes, colname].apply(lambda x:ast.literal_eval( "[" + x +"]"))

    #convert unpacked cells to list
    indexes = df[df[colname].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float))].index
    df.loc[indexes, colname] = df.loc[indexes, colname].apply(lambda x: [x,])

vals = [[userid, visit, unique_date, uniquefilename, unique_created, *rest_of_datas] for userid, visit, date, uniquefilename, created, *rest_of_datas in df.values.tolist() for unique_date in date for unique_created in created]
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns = df.columns.tolist())
for colname in ['Date', 'Created']:
    df[colname] = pd.to_datetime(df[colname], unit='ms', utc=True)
```

Comment: tgrandje, some of the values are floats (I changed the list, please see above), the code crashes at vals = [[unique, *vals] for colname, *vals in df.values.tolist() for unique in colname] with "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"

Comment: still no, may be it is getting values from other df's columns (I have a lot). could you please explain what vals = [[unique, *vals] for colname, *vals in df.values.tolist() for unique in colname] do?

Comment: I just assumed that your columns where starting with that one column... The *vals is a packed tuple, which means this expression is iterating on all rows ("for ... in df.values.tolist() ...") as lists. Afterward, it is just a matter of catching THE column and iterate over it's values. If you could post the correct order of columns (print df.columns.tolist() ), I could show you the correct way to do it.

Comment: ['UserID', 'Visit','Date', 'uniqueFileName', 'Created', 'dataCategory','fileType', 'technology'] - here 'Date' and 'Created' columns can have this issue

Comment: Just edited my answer. Hopes it will help you to understand the trick of the packed tuple (renamed *rest_of_datas for the occasion)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give it a try later today. Quick question - in the line vals = [[userid, visit, unique_date, uniquefilename, unique_created, *rest_of_datas] for userid, visit, date, uniquefilename, created, *rest_of_datas in df.values.tolist() for unique_date in date for unique_created in created] how does it correspond userid to 'UserID', visit to 'Visit' etc?

Comment: only by it's order : you iterate through columns - use print(df.values.tolist()[X]) to see how the Xth row is displayed (and the "for blah1, blah2, blah3 ... in ..." iterates through it, this a list comprehension synthax)